# The key specified is not a valid key for this encryption: Key size is not valid. Got key length of: 15

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, urlencode, secret-key, urldecode

I keep getting an error message when trying to send the key through url with `encodeforURL()` and `decodefromUrl()`. The code example is below.

This is my entry page:

```
key = generateSecretKey(("AES"),128);
data = encrypt(serializeJSON(pg_info), key, "AES", "HEX");
location("home.cfm?str=#encodeForURL(key)#&dt=#data#", "false", "301");
```

This is my home page:

```
if ( structKeyExists(url, "str") ) {
    key = DecodeFromURL(url.str);
    strData = deserializeJSON(decrypt(url.dt, key, "AES", "HEX")); // This is the line where the error message is pointing
} else {
    writeOutput("<p>Error! Please contact your administrator.</p>");
    abort;
}
```

The code is very simple. When user gets to the entry page the data parameters are being encrypted and sent trhough url to home page. Once user gets to home page data is extracted from ul. I tried adding the size when creating the secret key (128) in hope that issue will be resolved. The error is still happening and it seems that might be related to something else. I though that key length is the issue, but the error message is pointing to the line of code where url string is being applied to `deserializeJSON()`. Is there a way to find out what is causing an error an how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Don't you need to urlsafe-base64-encode the data first?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk is that something that will fix the problem I mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the technology here, I just know that encryption results are typically arbitrary bytes that must be encoded in some way to use them where strings are expected. urlsafe base64 encoding is typical, as is hex-encoding for such small sizes.

Comment: I don't see you extracting the key in the following `key = DecodeFromURL(url.str);`. Note that the key seems to be base 64 encoded (the whole library seems to be [Stringly Typed](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/#7), ugh). AES in there indicates that it is using CTR mode, so you should definitely also use an IV. I presume that sending the key is just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, I assume this code is just for testing purpose, since **passing the encryption key alongside the encrypted text utterly and completely defeats the purpose of encryption ;-)**

> Is there a way to find out what is causing an error

With troubleshooting, `location()` tends to get in the way, so best to temporarily replace it with a hyperlink. Then you'll be able to output the original key generated and compare it to what's actually received on the home page.

**Test Case (Single Page)**

```
<cfscript>
    // It make take a few executions to hit a failing key like `n+Py4flPF6uOwNXwpq2J4g==`. 
    pg_info = { "plain" : "text" };
    key     = "generateSecretKey(("AES"),128);
    data    = encrypt(serializeJSON(pg_info), key, "AES", "HEX");
    
    writeOutput( "[key] "& key &"<br>[encoded] "& encodeForURL(key) &"<br><br>");
    writeOutput( '<a href="#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#?str=#encodeForURL(key)#&dt=#data#">Test</a>' );
    

    if ( url.keyExists("str"))  {
    
        writeDump( var=[url.str], label="url.str (Original)" );
        writeDump( var=[DecodeFromURL(url.str)], label="url.str (Decoded)" );

        key = DecodeFromURL(url.str);
        strData = deserializeJSON(decrypt(url.dt, key, "AES", "HEX")); 
        writeDump( var=strData, label="strData" );
    }
    
</cfscript>
```

> how to fix this issue?

CF already decodes url parameters automatically. So decoding `url.str` a second time alters the original key value, causing decrypt() to fail because the key is no longer valid. Notice with a failing key like `n+Py4flPF6uOwNXwpq2J4g==` the original `url.str` value differs from the decoded `key`?

- **url.str (Original)** `n+Py4flPF6uOwNXwpq2J4g==` (has "+" char)
- **key (Decoded)** `n Py4flPF6uOwNXwpq2J4g==`  ("+" changes to space char)

Comment: I appreciate detailed response. Instead of using `encodeForURL()` and `decodeFromURL()` I only use `encodeForURL()` at the `entry.cfm` page. It seems that solved the problem. However, this is just for the testing purpuse, but I'm wondering how the key can be shared and passed between the pages securely? Thanks

Comment: It would have to be stored in a persistent scope, like application, etc